# How do I switch off from the main thread in Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

In Swift, if one dispatches a block of work to the main thread using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // work
   // myCallback()
}
```

Placing `print(Thread.current)` inside of myCallback indicates that it’s running on the main thread. How do get off the main thread at this point? Or, if I'm looking at this wrong, how can I know when some work I've sent to the main thread is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make something run on the the background thread manually, you can first get the global system queue with the specified quality-of-service class, then call its `async { code }` method to schedule a block for execution:

Example:

```swift
print(Thread.current)

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print(Thread.current)
}
```

Log:

```
<NSThread: 0x600003b60bc0>{number = 1, name = main}
<NSThread: 0x600003bcf340>{number = 14, name = (null)}
```

---

Documentation for [Dispatch Queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue);

Documentation for [`global(qos:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global).

Answer (score 0):

For use another thread you can use the follow.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "onde queue")

print(Thread.current)

queue.async {
    print(Thread.current)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(Thread.current)
    }
}
```

you have to create one queue, for change of thread, but when you are on another thread and you want to go back to main Thread you will use DispatchQueue.main.async